# Terminator: single window, focus on launch

Tags: window, shortcut-keys, terminator

I am configuring Terminator for my desktop. I use the `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T` shortcut to launch it. Since I want only a single instance running, I use `run-one terminator` as the launcher command.

Now if an Terminator instance is running, a new instance isn`t launched, but the **existing instance does not get focused**.

Any ideas as to how I could get the Terminator window to get focus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to install  **wmctrl** : `sudo apt-get install wmctrl` 
now the command `wmctrl -a STRING` gives focus to a window containing STRING in its title 
so your final command will be:

```
run-one terminator; wmctrl -a Terminator
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I have found a solution which works pretty well, detailed below.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a method that works without `run-one` assuming `wmctrl` is available:

```
wmctrl -xa terminator.Terminator || terminator
```

This assumes the default window class name is being used. You can get creative if you want and use a custom class name when launching `terminator`. This will allow you to keep your *terminator shortcut* separate from a normal *terminator* instance:

```
wmctrl -xa MyCustomTerminator.Terminator || terminator -c MyCustomTerminator
```

This just builds on Denis' answer without the need for `run-one`.

Comment: Any idea how to make it toggle the focus?

Comment: Great solution. I had to use `bash -c 'wmctrl -xa terminator.Terminator || terminator'` on Ubuntu 18.10 using Gnome 3.30.1. Otherwise the shortcut would only work once terminator was running already.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the hack I have settled upon using run-one and xdotool

In /home/(user)/my_scripts/single_terminator_instance.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# run a single instance of terminator
/usr/bin/run-one /usr/bin/terminator

# search for the terminator window and focus!!!
/usr/bin/xdotool search --onlyvisible --class terminator windowactivate
```

Then

1. Change Terminator shortcut command in `Main Menu` to point to the above script
2. In Keyboard shortcuts, `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T` activates the script

While searching across the i'net, I also chanced upon [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/install-terminator-with-built-in-quake.html)

Since I am new to bash scripts, I welcome any refinements to the hack!

Comment: Easier: `/usr/bin/wmctrl -xa terminator` :-) instead of xdotool! Thanks Denis.

Comment: you are right! right way is `wmctrl -xa terminator`

Comment: I tried your solutions, but run-one doesn't work on my computer with Terminator. It always launches a new instance. Do you have any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: `ps aux | grep terminator` returns nothing. The process runs as x-terminal-emulator for me, so that might be the cause. I did manual check like this:

RUNNING=$(ps aux | grep x-terminal-emulator | grep -v grep)

if [[ -z $RUNNING ]]; then
 x-terminal-emulator &
fi

Comment: @BartaTamás Did you solve your problem. My script is just two lines of bash attached to keyboard shortcut. I now use it with gnome-terminal and tmux, and am very happy with the solution. But it also works reliably with terminator. Maybe the same keyboard shortcut is assigned twice (Ctrl+Alt+T). Just guessing!