# How do I make terminator emulator appear and disappear like guake?

Tags: shortcut-keys, guake, terminator

I am using terminator 0.96 as terminal emulator. How can I make it run in the background and make it appear/disappear like guake terminal (i.e. using a shortcut key).

Comment: @hashken answer makes this really easy: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/install-terminator-with-built-in-quake.html

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88705/terminator-single-window-focus-on-launch

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was trying do the same thing (being a fan of both guake and terminator). Here's what I came up with (a customized version of [desqua](https://askubuntu.com/users/12943/desgua)'s answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127284/command-to-launch-an-application-or-to-show-its-window-if-already-launched?rq=1)):

**To launch an application or to show its window if already launched or to minimize if it is focused**

1) Install [wmctrl](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wmctrl) & [xdotool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool), or in a terminal: `sudo apt-get install wmctrl xdotool`

2) Make a script:

- Make a file gedit ~/bin/launch_focus_min.sh

And paste this:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                            
#
# This script does this:
# launch an app if it isn't launched yet,
# focus the app if it is launched but not focused,
# minimize the app if it is focused.
#
# by desgua - 2012/04/29
# modified by olds22 - 2012/09/16
#  - customized to accept a parameter
#  - made special exception to get it working with terminator


# First let's check if the needed tools are installed:

tool1=$(which xdotool)
tool2=$(which wmctrl)

if [ -z $tool1 ]; then
  echo "Xdotool is needed, do you want to install it now? [Y/n]"
  read a
  if [[ $a == "Y" || $a == "y" || $a = "" ]]; then
    sudo apt-get install xdotool
  else
    echo "Exiting then..."
    exit 1
  fi
fi

if [ -z $tool2 ]; then
  echo "Wmctrl is needed, do you want to install it now? [Y/n]"
  read a
  if [[ $a == "Y" || $a == "y" || $a = "" ]]; then
    sudo apt-get install wmctrl
  else
    echo "Exiting then..."
    exit 1
  fi
fi


# check if we're trying to use an app that needs a special process name
# (because it runs multiple processes and/or under a different name)
app=$1
if [[ $app == terminator ]]; then
  process_name=usr/bin/terminator
else
  process_name=$app
fi

# Check if the app is running (in this case $process_name)

#pid=$(pidof $process_name) # pidof didn't work for terminator
pid=$(pgrep -f $process_name)

# If it isn't launched, then launch

if [ -z $pid ]; then
  $app

else

  # If it is launched then check if it is focused

  foc=$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowpid)

  if [[ $pid == $foc ]]; then

    # if it is focused, then minimize
    xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize
  else
    # if it isn't focused then get focus
    wmctrl -x -R $app
  fi
fi

exit 0
```

- Make it executable: `chmod +x ~/bin/launch_focus_min.sh`

3) Make your keyboard shortcut:

- Open your keyboard settings and create a custom shorcut with the command: `/home/<user>/bin/launch_focus_min.sh terminator` (~/bin won't work)
- assign this command to Shift+Escape (or whatever keyboard shortcut you used for guake).

Comment: I tried this but it does not seem to work for me.

Comment: This is the perfect solution, The best of Guake with the best of Terminator, Thanks.

Comment: had to change "~/bin/launch_focus_min.sh terminator" into "/home/<user>/bin/launch_focus_min.sh terminator" for it to work for me

Comment: I had to add a bash shebang to the beginning of the file to get it to run properly under zsh: `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this would be use `xdotool`, and use the `windowunmap/windowmap` command to hide/unhide the desired class of windows. (This approach was not mentioned in the other answers that mention `xdotool`.) The solution will work well across all desktops, whatever window manager they are using. As the [manpage notes](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xdotool.1.html),

> In X11 terminology, mapping a window means making it visible on the screen.

So, unmapping a window will do the opposite and hide the window. Unfortunately, there is no toggle available to use with `xdotool` to switch between map/unmap states, but the two commands you need are below. The first hides the window:

```
xdotool search --class terminator windowunmap %@
```

and the second reverses the effect:

```
xdotool search --class terminator windowmap %@
```

Please note that if the window is already minimised, the `windowunmap` command will be unsuccessful.

For more information see `man xdotool`, the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xdotool.1.html), and [my answer to this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228312/how-to-emulate-pressing-the-close-button-from-a-script/228339#228339).

Answer (score 2):

By selecting a set of preferences in Terminator, you can make it work almost similar to Guake.

Refer to the following article for detailed explanation.
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/install-terminator-with-built-in-quake.html

I would advise you to follow all the steps in the article to get the desired results. I skipped a few steps, thinking they weren't necessary, but were actually needed to overcome some bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend simply using `yakuake`, a terminal in the same style as guake for the kde desktop.

You can install it by running `sudo apt-get install yakuake`.

Comment: Cannot leave terminator. I am using it since, last 2 years. Almost addicted to it by now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well the simplest solution would be just to **lock Terminator to launcher** and use the **shortcuts** that Ubuntu provides.

You can starts any application that is locked to launcher using the launcher shortcut:

**Super + 1 to 9**

For a full list of ready available shortcuts, hold the **Super** key.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script to raise and minimize the gnome terminal with byobu in linux mint, because guake has some weird console output messes. 
Then I added it to the shortcuts in the administrator keyboard->shurtcuts section.

script named *guake-toggling-for-gnome-terminal.sh*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if ! pgrep -x "gnome-terminal" > /dev/null
then
    gnome-terminal --app-id us.kirkland.terminals.byobu -e byobu
fi

byobuVisible=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible byobu)
byobuNotVisible=$(xdotool search byobu)
xdotool windowminimize ${byobuVisible}
xdotool windowraise ${byobuNotVisible}
```

Byobu is just the window name here.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't fully worked for me.

```
pgrep -f terminal // this does not give pid of renning terminator
```

I tweak this with

```
pid=`ps aux | grep terminator | awk '{print $2}'`
```

in line 54